# How can i get this kind of textview in android

Tags: android, textview

[image]

Is there any way get this kind of textview , I have used view, but as my textview height changed by amount of text, I cannot predefine the height of the view in xml or in the java,Thus the view can't get all the height of the textview.

Any solution??
I use this.But don't work...

```
<RelativeLayout
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_gravity="center"/>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/viewp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_below="@+id/title">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="7dp"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:text="hjdbcefc jc qec jcjejqf cmdn dchhwe c,we djh \n uydcvubcubcbwhchb"

   />

<View
    android:id="@+id/view"
    android:layout_width="5dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" <!--if I use here like 20dp, it shows otherwise not-->
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: use `drawableLeft` on the TextView

Comment: [Autosizing-Textview](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/autosizing-textview)

Comment: let the parent view height = wrapcontent,the textview height is wrap content and put a view width = 3dp,height = match_parent.

Comment: you can restrict the height of textview by using android:maxHeight. Property user for a set max height of textview.

Comment: @iAndroid But the text of textview from database.And there is no fixed limit of text.

Comment: @MD That is an interesting way.

Comment: @shadow please see my edit of the post.I used your solution.But don't work!

Comment: replace relative with linearlayout,let it orienttation = horizontal

Comment: also put the view before the textview btw

Comment: @shadow finally got it. Thanks

Comment: @ShahriarNasimNafi great!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a help @shadow I can figure out this solution

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="15dp"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="Be Greatful to you creator"
    />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/viewp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_below="@+id/title"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp">


    <View
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_width="5dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />




    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="23dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:text="Adults who frequently feel grateful have more energy, more optimism, more social connections and more happiness than those who do not, according to studies conducted over the past decade. They’re also less likely to be depressed, envious, greedy or alcoholics. They earn more money, sleep more soundly, exercise more regularly and have greater resistance to viral infections."

   /> </LinearLayout>
```

[image]